# Where did the families of astronauts watch the launch?

Tags: nasa, space-shuttle, astronauts, launch-site

Where did the families of American astronauts watch the launch from? I've heard the Saturn V Center and also the Launch Control Center. Maybe it was different for each launch? TIA

Answer (score 4):

They watched from the top of the Vehicle Assembly Building. I'm super jealous!

[Reference](http://johnweeks.com/sts130/index.html)

This video shows you what the view from there is like. (Not a launch, but you can see the crawlerway going out to the pads behind the speaker).